# Android Intent sending Stream directly

Tags: android, android-intent, stream, android-fileprovider

In my Android App I want to share data from my app. This could be any random data like an image I just created.
Currently I'm doing this via adding the Extra

```
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(file));
```

but that means I'm exposing the URI to the Intent receiver. Especially with Android API 24+ I have to implement this ugly FileProvider.
Since I don't really need to store the data in my app (I only want to share it e.g. by sending via Email or a file browser) I was hoping for simply sending the data directly. The "Intent.EXTRA_STREAM" suggests sending a stream directly without caring about file permissions etc.

So my question is:

Can I send an (output-)stream or the data directly from "app memory" in a manner of

```
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, myBitmap.getNiceOutputStream());
```

or even directly

```
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, myBitmap);
```

in order to avoid storing the file locally and using FileProviders?

--- EDIT ---

It appears I might create a custom ContentProvider sharing the data directly from within the App without saving it first to a file.
So any help pointing towards that solution will be welcome, too.

Comment: yes, use a custom `ContentProvider` instead

Comment: ***EXTRA_STREAM**-
**A content: URI holding** a stream of data associated with the Intent, used with ACTION_SEND to supply the data being sent.*   **obvious answer is NO** ... *I have to implement this ugly FileProvider* FileProvider is easy to to use and it is not ugly

Comment: Well I was hoping for a solution like the camera picture that delivers a tiny preview inside of it's intent return values. I read the API stating the URI would be required. But maybe there are other solutions that avoid the FileProvider completely.

Comment: And sure calling the FileProvider "ugly" is probably unfair. But I was trying to avoid storing the file locally first since that seems to be the way to do with a FileProvider.

Comment: so use a custom `ContentProvider` instead

Comment: Ah, so it is possible to create a custom ContentProvider that shares content directly from memory instead of a file? So I should edit my question then since I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: yes, you dont have to write the content you want to share to any file - you can serve your binary data "from memory" if you want to

Comment: Great, that sounds like what I was looking for. Any idea where to learn how to do that? Do you have a minimal example for - lets say - a a simple Bitmap from the App to an email client?

Comment: your impelmentation of `ContentProvider.openFile` should returns `ParcelFileDescriptor.createPipe()[0]` and you write to `ParcelFileDescriptor.createPipe()[1]` from the same `createPipe` call ... `FileProvider` is easier

Comment: override `ContentProvider#openFile(Uri uri, String mode)` method and use `ContentProvider#openPipeHelper()`

Comment: @Selvin so you mean, storing it in app cache and creating a FileProvider is the better solution? I found it a bit confusing creating a FileProvider for the internal / external cache storage.

Comment: in your shoes I would use FileProvider... there is no magic with `<cache-path name="name_customize_it" path="path_customize_it" /><provider
    android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="com.example"...>` `File imagePath = new File(Context.getCacheDir()(), "path_customize_it");
File newFile = new File(imagePath, "some_file.jpg");` use newFile(write bitmap to it) `Uri contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getContext(), "com.example", newFile);` and uri should looks like `content://com.example/name_customize_it/some_file.jpg` ready to share

Comment: Okay now, I used the FileProvider. Not sure who / how to thank you but it worked. :)

Comment: Hello I am facing the similar problem. I want to share my generated screenshot directly without saving it. do you have a few tips or a useful solution?

Comment: Sorry, that is really too far ago. I don't remember how/if I solved this. Still, the approach of a content provider seems the way to do.